# Fallback color for backdrop-filter: blur();

Tags: html, css

I'm currently using:

```css
.blurBox {
    background-color: #FFFFFF90;
    backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
}
```

But since FireFox doesn't currently support `backdrop-filter: blur()`, it uses the fallback of `#FFFFFF90`. The problem is that the fallback is too transparent. I can't simply change the fallback because it will affect the way the backdrop-filter looks as well.

My question is how do I make a separate fallback color that the backdrop-filter isn't reliant on?
I want to avoid doing browser-specific CSS if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try the [`@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) feature query in CSS:

```css
.blurBox {
  --fallback-background: #FFF9;
  --background: #FFF;
  background-color: var(--fallback-background); /* Fallback */
}
@supports (backdrop-filter: blur()) {
  .blurBox {
    background-color: var(--background);
    backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
  }
}
```

- **For browsers that don't understand what a supports query is:**
  They likely also don't support backdrop filter - so they will run the fallback, and then completely ignore everything inside the supports rule.
- **For browsers that don't support `backdrop-filter: blur()`:**
  They will run the fallback, and then ignore everything inside the supports rule.
- **For browsers that understand the supports query and support `backdrop-filter: blur()`:**
  Everything inside the supports rule will be run, and the background-color will override the fallback.

Comment: You probably don't want `inherit` though. By default background-color is `transparent` not inherit (which would set it to whatever the parent's bg-color is).

Comment: @Kaiido What do you reckon I should change it to in the answer?

Comment: `transparent` seems like the most common case, but maybe they want some bg-color in addition to the backdrop, it's up to them but `inherit` is rarely what you want and probably confusing.

Answer (score 0):

According to my ken you can't what you can do is use Hsl I think it will do the work (ofcourse not the blur effect) as there you can play with hue saturation and opacity.

```
background-color:hsl(5, 20%, 90%);
```

You can also use support

```
@supports (backdrop-filter: blur(1rem) {
 .blurBox {
    background-color: #FFFFFF90;
    backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
}
}
```